# Set of rows can not be sorted by a specific column

Tags: mysql, sorting, union, mariadb

I have scenario on MySQL MariaDB 10.20.1 where a resulting set of rows can not be sorted by a specific column.

Here is oversimplified example of this query

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
  SELECT *
    FROM Invoice
    WHERE /SOME_COMPLEX_CONDITION IS TRUE/
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
    FROM Invoice
    WHERE /ANOTHER_COMPLEX_CONDITION IS TRUE/
) D12 ORDER BY D12.Amount ASC;
```

Resulting set gets sorted in lexicographical order, rather then in ascending or descending order. The type of Invoice column is DECIMAL(X,Y), and there is not type conversion in the code.

I want directions where should I start my research on this?

Comment: There is no need to do the outer query, just enclose each query in the union by parentheses [ () ] and add an order by after the last query outside the parentheses.

Comment: I was gonna go with self-joins, but your advice did the trick much better, thank you

Comment: "MariaDB 10.20.1" -- Eh?  No such version.

Comment: Can't reproduce with 10.0.21, works fine for me with outer query ordering by decimal(10,2) field from the inner query ...